# Some problems on tinyos on the lesson Mote-PC serial communication

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04, tinyos

I'm now facing some problems maybe about java when learning tinyos.

[image: Here is the picture]

Also there is some settings about my  java  and the tinyos.sh

```
 //.bashrc
    # Start TinyOS environment pathing  
    export TOSROOT=/opt/tinyos-2.1.2  
    export TOSDIR=$TOSROOT/tos  
    export CLASSPATH=$TOSROOT/support/sdk/java/tinyos.jar:.$CLASSPATH  
    export MAKERULES=$TOSROOT/support/make/Makerules  
    export PATH=/opt/msp430/bin:$PATH  
    source /opt/tinyos-2.1.2/tinyos.sh  
    # End TinyOS pathing  

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0
export JRE_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}/jre 
export CLASSPATH=.:${JAVA_HOME}/lib:${JRE_HOME}/lib
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH

# TinyOS 2.1.2 Configuration Guide  
# Here we setup the environment  
# variables needed by the tinyos   
# make system  

echo "Setting up for TinyOS 2.1.2"  
export TOSROOT="/opt/tinyos-2.1.2" 
export TOSDIR="$TOSROOT/tos"  
export MAKERULES="$TOSROOT/support/make/Makerules"   
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$TOSROOT/support/sdk/python
exportCLASSPATH=
$CLASSPATH:$TOSROOT/support/sdk/java:.:$TOSROOT/support/sdk/java/tinyos.jar
```

If any suggestion, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem pretty much lies in your classpath, try:

```
CLASSPATH="$TOSROOT/support/sdk/java/tinyos.jar:$TOSROOT/support/sdk/java:$TOSROOT
        /support/sdk/java/net/tinyos:{Insert_folder_where_NesC_Is}/nesc-1.3.4/tools:."
```

The classpath above should pretty much cover every java related thing you could possibly need.

Comment: well.. i find that  i dont even have a folder NesC.

Comment: hi！ i just finish this problem. Actually you are right, i miss the classpath for tinyos.jar . Thank you very much！